# Sencha suddenly items disappear

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have my controls and they were visible. Now all of a sudden out of nowhere today they look like this:

[image]

Whereas prior there was a picker in each. I haven't changed any code how come this has happened all of a sudden?

Update: This only happens in the new version of Google Chrome (v29). it doesn't happen in Safari. How can I get passed this? Is it a chrome bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug with Sencha and Chrome 29. You have to tweak Sencha's Mixin `st-box` to work around that bug.

The Mixin can be found in `resources/themes/stylesheets/sencha-touch/base/mixins/_Class.scss`

Change it to:

```
@mixin st-box($important: no) {
    @if $important == important {
        display: flex !important;
        display: -webkit-box !important;
       display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    } @else {
        display: flex;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
    }
 }
```

Then recompile your css and the bug should be gone.

Here is the official announcement of that workaround:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/announcement.php?f=90&a=43